# Do we setup cron base on local time or UTC time

Tags: magento-1.8, cron

I have a system cron that run every 15 minutes that invoke the magento cron.sh. Inside the  magento module config.xml, I setup crontab to run at 1 am

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <catalogrule_apply_all>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>0 1 * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>catalogrule/observer::dailyCatalogUpdate</model>
            </run>
        </catalogrule_apply_all>
    </jobs>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_get_final_price>
            <observers>
                <catalogrule>
                    <class>catalogrule/observer</class>
                    <method>processAdminFinalPrice</method>
                </catalogrule>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_get_final_price>
    </events>
</crontab>
```

Is this 1 AM the local time or the UTC time? because I think magento is using UTC time only when store data into db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be server time. Use "date" to check the server time and timezone.

Comment: Also, can you tell me if I should use cron.sh or cron.php in my crontab?

Comment: Usually cron.php

Comment: Thank you, I got 1 more question, please help http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25694/how-to-override-crontab-of-existing-module