# How to override crontab of existing module

Tags: magento-1.8, cron, schedule

I dont want Mage_Newsletter to constantly send out email, so I create a custom module inside `local` to take out the cron,

```
#/var/www/html/public_html/app/code/local/MyComp/CustomConfig/etc/config.xml
<config>
  <modules>
    <MyComp_CustomConfig>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </MyComp_CustomConfig>
  </modules>
  <crontab>
    <jobs>
        <newsletter_send_all>
            <run>
                <model>newsletter/observer::scheduledSend</model>
            </run>
        </newsletter_send_all>
    </jobs>
  </crontab>
</config>
```

Note, how I dont have tag `<schedule>`

then inside

```
#/var/www/html/public_html/app/etc/modules/MyComp_CustomConfig.xml
<config>
  <modules>
    <MyComp_CustomConfig>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </MyComp_CustomConfig>
    <depends>
        <Mage_Newsletter />
    </depends>
  </modules>
</config>
```

I still see `newsletter_send_all` being execute inside table 'cron_schedule' after I clean cache. I tried to add the

```
<schedule>
   <cron_expr>0 3 * * *</cron_expr>
</schedule>
```

which run at 3AM, clear cache and refresh, but `newsletter_send_all` still execute immediately  in my table (not yet 3 AM). Please help, what am I missing?

Note: my server time is not UTC, it run with local timezone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the way I usually do it and it works.
Here is what I think your problem is with this specific cron.
By default the `newsletter_send_all` job is set to run every 5 minutes.
When running `cron.php` magento executes the jobs that should run at this moment but schedules ahead for the next X minutes (I think 20 minutes).
So if you first executed the cron and the `newsletter_send_all` was still set at 5 minutes then 3 (or 4) additional jobs for `newsletter_send_all` were scheduled in for the next run.

After that you changed the `cron_expr` and executed the cron again, but the 3 jobs that were scheduled before are still scheduled so they will be executed.

Give it half an hour or so and run the cron again. See if the newsletter is sent again.

And I strongly recommend this extension: https://github.com/fbrnc/Aoe_Scheduler. Among other cool stuff it allows you to see when every cron is scheduled, and if your changed to the `cron_expr` are taken into consideration.